# Write Registery bat

Tags: batch-file, cmd

When writing a `bat` file I'm expecting the output to contain a `%`, however as you can see it isn't being outputted. Why is this happening?

```
rem start.reg
@echo off
echo @="\"C:\\Users\\Administrator\\bat\\start.bat\" 1%" >> "start.reg"
pause
```

Result is :

```
@="\"C:\\Users\\Administrator\\bat\\start.bat\" 1"
```

Comment: Parameters/Arguments use `%1` not `1%` you'll need to double up the `%` though, `%%1`

Comment: Made question more clear.